# Choosing a suitable sample size for a Random Forest Model

Tags: classification, sample-size, train-test-split

I know that this isn't always a straight forward question to answer, but I am working on a provincial wide wetland classification model that has $7$ classes and $32$ or so explanatory variables. In my model, I have a $92 \%$ OA and somewhere in the ball park from $90 - 98$ PA and UA. After inspecting the model and using it daily for my research, I am finding it to be fairly accurate.

I have $2000$ training/validation points. $20 \%$ were validation.

I stopped training the model and building my training and validation set once I started getting the results I was looking for. Do you think my sample size is large enough and is it defensible?

Comment: Of possible interest: https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-137

Comment: Have you only produced one model? Have you attempted cross-validation? Or is there a reason you can't do it?

Comment: Hi, I have created several variations yes and cross validated. @MarkoLalovic

Comment: @J-J-J thanks for this! Very helpful! I have heard something like this before. Is your interpretation that you need 10 times the amount of variables per class? For example if I have 30 variables and 7 classes, therefore I need 2100 points or 10 times the variables for the entire model? I am assuming per class?